# Update Content Page from Master

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have a master page and a content page.  Not quite sure how to do this.  How do I reset/refresh the content page after I do something in the Master page.  The something I'm doing is changing a dropdown list and which then dictates what you can see in the content page.  If I could call the page load of the content page from the master page that would do it.

Thank you

Comment: Handle a custom event of the masterpage in the page.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Not quite sure how to do that.  Can you give an example please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Handle a custom event of the masterpage in the page.

```
//Event in MasterPage
public delegate void SomethingSelected(object sender, String SelectedValue);
public event SomethingSelected OnSomethingSelected;

//SelectedIndexChanged event in MasterPage
protected void DropDonwnList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OnSomethingSelected(sender, ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue);
}
```

The content page(assuming the type of it is called `SiteMaster`):

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender,EventArgs e){
    var master = (SiteMaster)Page.Master;
    master.OnSomethingSelected +=  MasterSelected;
}

private void MasterSelected(object sender, string selectedValue)
{ 
    // now you can handle the master's event and update your content page
}
```

Comment: Hi @Tim, i know it's too old post, actually i am facing a same problem, i have a dropdown in master page, which lists the currencies, and then in the content page, i want to show the calculated value based on the selected currency, i tried your mentioned method, but when the dropdown gets changed, it first loads the content page, and then goes to the dropdowns selectedindex event and then raises the custom event, but by that time, the content page data has already been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

For the sequence of events, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx.  Specically, "*Master pages behave like child controls on a page: the master page Init event occurs before the page Init and Load events, and the master page Load event occurs after the page Init and Load events.*"